# className on children affects parent element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im building a card object and I want it to have the className `.card` which is defined in css like this:

```
.card img{position:absolute; width:150px; height:160px}
```

which mean I want only the images inside my div to cover each other and not the div's themselves. Every time a create 2 or more cards, they cover each other as if they had the `position: absolute` property.

My JavaScript Code:

```
  this.add = function()
  {
    console.log("add");
    this.container.appendChild(this.backImg);
    this.container.appendChild(this.frontImg);
    this.container.className = "card";
    document.body.appendChild(this.container);
  };
};

var card1 = new Card(1);
card1.add();
```

Comment: When you set an element to `position: absolute` it is taken outside the document flow. Which means its parent shrinks in size accordingly. You can either set the parent's width and height, or not set the first child's position to absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the same width and height of the images to the container card, that way:

```
.card { position: relative; width:150px; height:160px }
```